# How to avoid hyperlink creation when writing down URIs in markdown?

Tags: url, hyperlink, uri, markdown

I would like to know how to avoid the automatic generation of links when I write down an URI in a site that accepts Markdown Language.

I know how to do it in this forum, by making use of the code blocks (for example):  `http://stackoverflow.com`

But this trick doesn't work in some places (for example in http://datahub.io).

So given the basic markdown as described here: http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax , how could I write down URIs to make them as plain text when parsed (or maybe, how to avoid the parser for a chunk of text, I suppose that would make the trick as well).

Any suggestion would be good appreciated.

Jesús.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way, but this very nasty hack seems to do the trick:

```
http[]()://example.com/
```

I've jammed Markdown's radar with some empty markup (an empty link
with no text).

Answer (score 23):

I'm guessing nobody mentioned this because it's anathema for markdown.... but you can just do this:

```
<span>https://example.com</span>
```

Comment: This works for `<span>ASP.NET</span>` in an Azure DevOps Wiki article - it irks me that it always wants to linkify that

Comment: I’d argue this is the proper answer. By design, Markdown is limited and asks you to drop into HTML for things it doesn’t support. Granular control of auto-linking is one such thing.

Comment: This did not work in Azure DevOps - project's README.md file for me. Instead had to use the answer from @forestj - `ASP.[]()NET`

Comment: Also didn't work for me, but I stuck with the original idea and went with:
`https://example<span>.</span>com`.

Answer (score 7):

One solution to this is the use of [**HTML character entity references**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML#Character_references) (AKA character codes):

```markdown
https&#58;&#47;&#47;www&period;example&period;com

example&period;com
```

This evalutes to:

https://www.example.com

example.com

You can use one of the [**named entities**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) or the code point in decimal (`&#nnnn;`) or hexadecimal (`&#xhhhh;`) form, for any character that might trigger link detection.

Comment: In Azure DevOps markdown even the character entities get parsed, so this trick doesn't work there. (Wish it did, because this seems the proper way to do it.) Anyway, I ended up doing it like this: `https://example<span>.</span>com`

Comment: @intrepidis I've found I have to use empty links/fragments or HTML tags in some Markdown implementations, too. None of the solutions here seems to work globally, so it's helpful to have all three in the toolbelt.

Comment: example&period;com worked in Azure wiki

Answer (score 6):

A more aesthetically pleasing alternative to the first answer (breaking up the URL with `[]()`) is to insert your own HTML-like tag—call it whatever makes sense to you:

`https<nolink>://example.com`

Look Ma, no hyperlink!
https://example.com

Credit: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119811/411046

Comment: ... and then sometime in the future `<nolink />` becomes a new HTML tag, and your pages start screwing up. (possibly)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using matrix (the chat protocol, https://matrix.org/)  or [linkifyjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linkifyjs),

then none of the above mentioned are guaranteed to work. (for example, the popular matrix client [element](https://element.io/) [uses](https://github.com/matrix-org/matrix-react-sdk/blob/fe0a68b71ea81230bb662be0c8b89a56c97542bc/src/linkify-matrix.ts#L205) [linkify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linkifyjs). However, this will work:

```
https:/<del></del>/example.<del></del>com should work in any matrix clients that support rich formatting
```

```
https:/[]()/example.[]()com  should work
```

Comment: This is the fix that worked in Azure DevOps - project's README.md file. Had to put `[]()` before or after the period like `asp.[]()net`. Other ideas didn't work - not `[]()asp.net`, and not `<span>asp.net</span>`.

Answer (score 2):

Somehow this:

```
- [x] Objects Spec Update Idea.md
```

got turned into a link

```
Idea.md
```

leading to

```
http://idea.md
```

What I did is enclose it in back tick characters ` like this:

```
- [x] `Objects Spec Update Idea.md`
```

(Back tick characters make it format as inline code and seems to keep the characters more in tact more literally in the output.)

I hope this works for some of you too.

Comment: This is nice, but I found that using back-ticks leads to a different formatting of the text.